# FATAL: attempting to release access but the mutator does not have access

Tags: react-native, ios11

I'm having trouble trying to figure out where to even look for this new issue that I'm seeing.  I'm running `react-native` version `0.44.1` and I get a crash.  The log in xcode shows:

`FATAL: Attempting to release access but the mutator does not have access.`

In the stack trace, I see it is `UIApplicationMain`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  @autoreleasepool {
    return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
  }
}
```

In `UIApplicationMain` trace:

```
0x113f2091d <+159>: movq   0x1099bf4(%rip), %rbx     ; (void *)0x000000011042ad50: objc_release
```

What should I be attempting to find to root cause this issue?

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this? I'm seeing it frequently, though unpredictably in an RN 0.49 app, ever since updating to iOS 11/xcode 9. It seems to be thrown by WebKit's JavascriptCore (during garbage collection I guess). I'm using Chrome's debugger. I haven't seen the crash on a real device yet but I spend most of my time with the simulator.

The only third-party native libs I'm using are Realm and OneSignal, so if all else fails I'll try stripping everything back.

I'm surprised it's not a more popular question given I don't think I'm doing anything unusual!

Comment: @RobHogan I have been working on a new react native (0.49) app for the past couple days, and I never got this until I added Realm. It was one of the two external dependencies you had so maybe its doing something funky

Comment: My react-native link command doesn't add `libRealmReact.a`. Add it to `Link Binary with Libraries` and make sure it's before `libRealmJS.a`

Give that a go

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Realm, there is a chance you've hit the following issue:

https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1095

Unfortunately, the easiest fix appears to be disabling remote JS debugging (which I can confirm worked for me).

Comment: Works for me too - thanks. Looks like a realm-remote debugger issue, possibly only with iOS 11.